# repeat same headers on newly created worksheets in ms excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a already existing excel file with some headers and single worksheet, I want that whenever a user click on add new worksheet button headers should be repeated on the it.Is it possible, if yes please tell be the steps to create one excel like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template, although that's a question for the superuser site.

As a macro answer try this:

1. Create a new worksheet with only the header on it, Rename this sheet Template.
2. Go into the Developer tab and insert an ActiveX button, double click it to go into the vba editor (you may need to save your document as a macro enabled document first)
3. Change the name of your button to btnNewWorkSheet and the caption to something like "Click here for a new worksheet"
4. Go into the sheets page in the VBA editor and copy this code:

   ```
   Private Sub btnNewWorkSheet_Click()
       Sheets("Template").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
   End Sub
   ```

---

Now you can click on the button on any page where it appears to create a copy of the Template page

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the following code to "ThisWorkbook" module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
  If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
    Sheet1.Range("A1:K1").Copy Sh.Range("A1")
  End If
End Sub
```

Sheet1 is the name of the single worksheet object, replace `A1:K1` with the range of your headers, replace `A1` with the desired destination.